# "too many HTTP redirects" while using Alamofire Upload Multipart Form Data

Tags: ios, afnetworking, multipartform-data, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm using Alamofire 3 and encountered this:

```
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x15eb422d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1007 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=URL omitted, NSErrorFailingURLKey= URL omitted, NSLocalizedDescription= too many HTTP redirects}
```

while calling this method:

```
upload(.POST, kTaskSubmitImageUrl, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: result, name: "uploaded")
            },
            encodingCompletion:{ encodingResult in

                switch encodingResult
                {
                    case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON{
                            responseData in
                            debugPrint(responseData)
                        }
                    case .Failure(let errorStatus) :
                        debugPrint(errorStatus)
                }
            }
        )
```

anybody know whats going on about it? Should I look at my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out that in iOS 9, there's this  App Transport Security (ATS) to enforce best practices in secure connections between an app and its back end. Hence the redirect issues.

by adding `Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = nil`

everything works like magic XD

Cheers

Des

Comment: I think this is in swift. can you please tell me about obj c also.

Comment: i don't know how but it was auto resolved with internet speed. It was due to slow speed of internet.