# AFNetworking error too many http redirects iOS 9

Tags: ios, http, redirect, afnetworking

Since today I've got some serious problems with AFNetworking requesting an https link where I want to get back some XML-Info, yesterday it already worked and I also sent out some TestFlight-Links, so it's very frustrating. I also didn't do any changes to the server configuration.

But today I'm just getting the error -1007 "too many http redirects". Did someone also had a problem like this? I already saw a post of iOS 9: ["too many HTTP redirects" while using Alamofire Upload Multipart Form Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727493/too-many-http-redirects-while-using-alamofire-upload-multipart-form-data) 
But I can't find this property they are talking of.
Can someone help me please?
Here is the configuration of the data task im doing for getting my response-XML, hope this helps.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:35];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];    

showNetworkActivityIndicator();
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];


NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Log error object
        NSLog(@"AFNetworking error response: %@\n\n\n", error);

    } else {
 //       NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);

        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

thanks for help!
best regards

Comment: What URL are you going to? The error seems straightforward - the URL you're hitting is redirecting you too many times.

Comment: I know the errortext says everything - but we haven't changed anxthing in the background everything is like before the error occured. like I said it worked the day before and in the browser everything works fine :-S

Comment: oh yes - a https url, I'm not allowed to post this here because of the restrictions the customer maid, but I can send it in a private message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, occurred when I tried to send request when server was unavailable. Then when server comes alive - this error occured.

This helped me:

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Comment: This did solve my problem, however, my concern is, since URLCache is from Foundation, if i consistently remove all cachedresponse, how will that affect other networking service (a.k.a kingfisher)?